# Water pump that can shut down if no water from supplier

Tags: water

Presently we are suffering water supply crisis in which there is not enough water supply for the population so water supply has to be turned on or off by the supplier.

What kind of water pump that can shut itself off if there is no water? Usually for normal water pump, it still pumps even if no water is flowing.

(note: I'll be using pressure tank, not storage tank so there is no float. One can't put it inside the pressure tank itself. So I need something that can detect water flow not by level.)

Comment: Ususally sensors are fitted to detect the amount or level of water upstream of the tank..

Comment: What kind of sensors? Are these independent from.the water pump?

Answer (score 1):

The HC6000 can turn on an outlet at a certain water level and turn off the outlet at a certain water level.  Attach an AC pump and this is an example of a pump that can turn off when the water level is too low.

[https://www.amazon.com/HC6000-Hi-Lo-Controller-Float-Switch/dp/B006AU4L4U/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=hc6000&qid=1554961547&s=gateway&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006AU4L4U)

Comment: But I'll be using pressure tank, not storage tank so there is no float. One can't put it inside the pressure tank itself. So I need something that can detect water flow not by level.

Answer (score 1):

We have a water treatment system that injects diluted chlorine into the piping when there is water flow detected. I used The Google to search for "water flow switch" which returned many results. I discovered that these switches are used for salt water pool systems as well as drinking water treatment systems.

The switch in our system is a vertical pipe in which gravity causes the "trigger" device to settle over the opening in the pipe. When water flows, the disk of the trigger lifts to the top of the enclosure, allowing water to exit at 90°, while simultaneously placing a magnet within range of a reed switch, triggering the pump.

For your application, if the switch you select does not have Normally Closed/Normally Open options, you may have to use a relay for pump control. That's a minor consideration, but is another point of failure overall.

One of the items [(Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LVTXQZR) from my search uses a hall effect sensor with a small propeller within the coupling, reading a magnet on one of the blades.

[image: flow sensor]

This type of switch would require a circuit to recognize the signal (or lack of) and trigger accordingly which could be accomplished with an Arduino or similar small-board-computer.

Coincidentally, I later searched for a booster pump to be able to wash solar panels from the ground. [Amazon sells a booster pump](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DCQLNXB) to run on 110v house current (USA) and incorporates the switch noted above, which makes is a "turnkey" purchase, a stand-alone system that will likely perform as you've indicated.

Comment: I need a complete unit with plugs and outlets. Any ideas where to buy them?

Comment: Edited to add new information of value.

Comment: Well I live in asia and use 240v :) I guess options are so limited now as the only ones available at 110v or so